# Cluster or worker node need to be created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am getting error while trying to get default namespace in EKS instance.

Do i need to create a cluser or worker node, as it appears i am missing a cluster.

Or i need to do a fresh kubectl installation, if so what are the commands to remove and reinstall.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

Something is very wrong with your `kubectl` binary at least. Even if you have an invalid kubeconfig, or your cluster is down, `kubectl` won't segfault like that.

You could try just running `kubectl` by itself to see if it dumps core just printing out the options, but you're probably better off checking your installed `kubectl` against a known-good version.

This isn't anywhere near a k8s problem yet, so try reinstalling `kubectl`.

Comment: can you tell me the commands/doc to safe uninstall and reinstall